# Grails 3 intergration test migration for grails.test.MockUtils grails.test.GrailsMock

Tags: grails, grails3

I have a number of integration tests failing in grails 3 (which were passing in grails 2) because it cannot resolve the imports:

- grails.test.MockUtils
- grails.test.GrailsMock

I cannot find any documentation about how I should migrate them. 
Does anyone know what I should migrate them to?

Comment: https://testing.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html#upgrading

Comment: thanks for the link -- looking at the table of contents they have yet to focus on integration tests.  I am added the @Integration annotation to mine and extending 'specification' .  The only other documentation I can find is [http://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/guide/upgrading.html] :  "Step 8 - Migrate Tests

Integration tests will need to be annotated with the Integration annotation and should not extend GroovyTestCase or any JUnit 3 super class."

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example integration test from a grails 3.2 project

```
import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.transaction.Rollback
import spock.lang.Specification

@Integration
@Rollback
class SomeServiceIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

    SomeService someService
```

Notice the Rollback annotation can be used to clean up after each test